# How to bundle text files into an xcode application to be readable at runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode, resources

I have added a few `.js` files to an `xcode` project:

[image]

I am trying to load those `.js` files at runtime but they apparently are not available. This was seen by looking at the physical disk location of the simulator sandbox that we can find at: `Bundle.main.bundlePath` whose value is:

> /Users/steve/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CC7AE0CD-4EEE-412F-8E01-E5F55F73887E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ECB90596-FF9F-4E40-B500-0D55DDFC0E2E/hybrid.app

Under that directory there are a few `gyb` files, the `Info.plist`, some code signature files, the `storyboard` .. and *one* `.js` file.  That one file was added to the project earlier and I am not certain using what mechanism.

I'd be happy to see *all* of the `.js` files there - but maybe that's too much to ask?  Is there a different way to get those other `.js` files - like reading from some `Resources` bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise in more deeply understanding `xcode` project structures and `Build phases`.   Go to the `Project Properties` then select the `Build Phases` tab.  Select the `Copy Bundle Resources` and add the files - `javascript` in my case - in that section:

[image]

The files now do show up in the root directory of the simulator output sandbox directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag any file into the Project navigator (project files structure browser) pane on the left. This file will be accessible via

```
let jsonFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "js")
```

Comment: I had done that and the `.js` did not show up: see the OP screenshot.  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Another consideration: just dropping files may lead to xcode attempting to compile them.

Comment: select a js file and on the right pane (File Inspector) on a bottom side you will find a "Target Membership" list. The checkbox should be checked.

Comment: I drug the file `sudoku-1000.csv` into my project and the following still fails: `if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sudoku-1000", ofType: "csv")`